# Tento Rodar uma funçao em python e ela me retorna none

Tags: python, array, funções

Desculpe se a minha dúvida parece boba eu sou novato ainda mas é o seguinte, criei uma função em python que deveria me retornar uma lista com esse caractere dentro "~". Aqui esta a função:

```
def escreva(texto):
   lista = []
   cont = 0
   while cont < len(texto)
     lista = ['~']
     cont += 1


a = str(input('Entre com o texto'))
print(a)
print(escreva(a))
```

Quero que essa lista fique do tamanho do texto que foi digitado só que quando rodo o programa ele me mostra a string digitada e a palavra none :

```
String (O texto qualquer que eu digitei e mandei printar)
None
```

Gostaria de saber porque ele me retorna a palavra none e como poderia fazer essa lista ficar do tamanho do texto.

Answer (score 4):

Há alguns problemas no seu código.

Primeiro, você não esta usando a palavra chave `return` para especificar a variável e o valor a ser retornado pela função, simplesmente adicione ao seu código:

```
return lista
```

Segundo, mesmo adicionando o `return` seu programa vai retornar uma lista com apenas um elemento que é o `~`, porque você usa o `=` para reatribuir o vetor para sua variável lista:

```
['~']
```

Para corrigir use o método `append`, [veja aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). Veja como ficou o código:

```
def escreva(texto):
    lista = []
    cont = 0

    while cont < len(texto):
        lista.append('~')
        cont += 1
    return lista

a = str(input('Entre com o texto:'))
print(a)
print(escreva(a))
```

Entrada:

> texto

Saída:

> ['~', '~', '~', '~', '~']

Também não precisa converter o valor retornado pela função `input` porque ela já retorna uma string, faça:

```
a = input('Entre com o texto:')
```

Leia sobre a função [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: Poderia também usar list comprehension `return ["~" for _ in texto]` ou ate mesmo (caso nao precise checar nenhum valor) simplesmente `return ["~"] * len(text)`

Comment: Sim, mais segui a logica dele :)